# Vim Prettier with vim Plug

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, prettier

I tried installing Prettier with vim plug but doesn't work.
PlugInstall installs successfully without any errors.
but :prettier command says it's not a command

vimrc:

```
Plug 'prettier/vim-prettier', { 'do': 'yarn install' }
```

Thank You :D

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to add this line to your .vimrc

```
let g:prettier#exec_cmd_path = "~/path/to/cli/prettier"
```

To know the path you must go to your vim-prettier directory and enter to **package.json** (for example) and use this command

```
:PrettierCliPath
```

Finally, copy and paste the path to your .vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

From Vim prettier [docs](https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier)

> Install with vim-plug, assumes node and yarn|npm installed globally.

So make sure that you have those dependencies installed in your system.

Also use `:Prettier`, note the first character is in uppercase.

Comment: All three are installed i checkd the versions too. it says no Prettier executable installation found :(

Comment: Then you need to install the prettier either in your project or install it globally. You can do that by using `npm i prettier`.

Comment: still doesn't work I installed prettier with npm now I'm getting an error Prettier: failed to parse buffer. Btw Thank you very much for looking into this :D

Comment: @SandevAbeykoon do you have prettierrc file? What is the output for following command in vim `:PrettierCliPath` ?

Comment: No I do not have prettierrc file the output :PrettierCliPath - no Prettier executable installation found.

Comment: Hey i used npm install -g prettier after that when I used the command Prettier it says failed to parse buffer

Comment: Now when i used :PrettierCliPath i get prettier

Comment: Thank You very much for some reason it started working while fiddling with vimrc thank you very much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my problem was that I didn't install yarn, check if you have yarn:
yarn --version

if you don't try deleting prettier by deleting it in you .vimrc file and running :PlugClean
Install yarn before installing prettier, to install yarn:
npm install --global yarn

This worked for me hope it works for you to